# Geometric conditions on motivic fibrations

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, model-categories, motivic-homotopy

What are the geometric conditions on a map of varieties/schemes being a motivic fibration (i.e. a fibration in the motivic model structure on simplicial presheaves on affine schemes)?

For example, are the étale maps motivic fibrations? Are the flat maps motivic fibrations outside of singular fibers?

I recognize that this question is probably extremely basic, so if there is a good reference that contains an answer, this would be quite enough.

Comment: I do not consider this as basic at all. There are basic results in the work of Matthias Wendt, such as https://arxiv.org/abs/1009.2930 or https://arxiv.org/abs/1011.4784 The case of torsors under a group scheme already leads to rather deep results. You may have a look at the series of papers by Aravind Asok, Marc Hoyois and Matthias Wendt "Affine representability results in A1-homotopy theory I, II, III".